# Arch Linux GRUB не загружает ОС

Tags: linux, unix, grub, archlinux, lvm

Установил Arch Linux на LVM по официальной инструкции, устанавливал и раньше не раз, только на UEFI, а сейчас вот впервые установил на DOS(MBR) и возникла проблема, GRUB просто показует консоль при загрузке, не какого меню или rescure console, просто promt, не каких ошибок и т.д.
Из консоли граба ОС вполне загружается при такой последовательности команд:

```
insmod lvm
linux (lvm/vg0-rootfs)/boot/vmlinux-image root=/dev/mapper/vg0-rootfs
initrd (lvm/vg0-rootfs)/boot/initramfs-linux.img
boot
```

Вот некоторая информация о установленой мною системе:
lsblk:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0             11:0    1  602M  0 rom  
vda            254:0    0   20G  0 disk 
└─vda1         254:1    0   20G  0 part 
  └─vg0-rootfs 253:0    0    5G  0 lvm  /
```

cat /etc/fstab:

```
# UUID=a6aedb90-f585-47a8-a69a-6a59cc923f75
/dev/mapper/vg0-rootfs  /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1
```

cat /etc/mkinitcpio.conf | grep ^HOOKS:

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck)
```

sudo cat /boot/grub/grub.conf:
https://pastebin.com/YTkaXutu

Уже перепроверял все что только можно, все делал точно по инструкции, не понимаю почему GRUB не загружает ОС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема как выяснилось была в неправильном имени файла конфигурации GRUB2, вместо `grub.cfg` я его назвал `grub.conf`